Is passing a callback to a component as children a good pattern in React?
I noticed that Optimizely sdk suggest to implement the following like this and found it interesting.
<OptimizelyFeature feature="price_filter">
  {(isEnabled, variables) => (
     isEnabled
       ? `Price filter enabled with a min price of ${variables.min_price}`
       : `Price filter is NOT enabled`
  )}          
</OptimizelyFeature>

in their code they basically do this
const FeatureComponent: React.FunctionComponent<FeatureProps> = props => {
  const { feature, timeout, autoUpdate, children, overrideUserId, overrideAttributes } = props;
  const [isEnabled, variables, clientReady, didTimeout] = useFeature(
    feature,
    { timeout, autoUpdate },
    { overrideUserId, overrideAttributes }
  );

  if (!clientReady && !didTimeout) {
    // Only block rendering while were waiting for the client within the allowed timeout.
    return null;
  }

  // Wrap the return value here in a Fragment to please the HOC's expected React.ComponentType
  // See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18051
  return <>{children(isEnabled, variables, clientReady, didTimeout)}</>;
};

I'm wondering if this anti-pattern? isn't a different type what they are passing?. Would it be better to pass it as a callback then the callback is used for rendering?

"isn't a different type what they are passing?. Would it be better to pass it as a callback" - what do you mean? It does pass a callback that is then used for rendering.

Passing a callback as children in React, often referred to as the "Function as a Child Component" (FaCC) pattern, is not considered an anti-pattern. It is a well-established and valid approach.
An alternative to FaCC is to use a render prop, which is essentially the same concept but passed as a prop instead of children:
<OptimizelyFeature
  feature="price_filter"
  render={(isEnabled, variables) => (
    isEnabled
      ? `Price filter enabled with a min price of ${variables.min_price}`
      : `Price filter is NOT enabled`
  )}
/>


Below I’ve linked a presentation by Tanner Linsley (founder of TanStack) regarding development on react-table.
Around the 5 minute mark he discusses the benefit of “headless UI”, where he uses this same pattern to let the implementer define their own table UI, while letting the library’s API do a lot of the heavy lifting.
He also mentions how hooks can be used in place of this, but this pattern (FaCC and Render Props) are still very common and very useful.
Reference
